# Want to download DotNetOpenAuth .zip file

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I wanted to learn from the samples that come with DotNetOpenAuth .zip.

I am trying to download the DotNetOpenAuth-4.0.3.12163 .zip file from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/latest/download

but after downloading, when I try to unzip, I get the message that the zip file is invalid.

I got the dlls from the NuGet link, but could not get the DotNetOpenAuth samples. Do we have them available somewhere else...?

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the download, and "it works for me".  Can you try downloading again to see if it was corrupted during download for you?

Comment: yes something is invalidating it during the download - in my company network. I should have thought that. Thanks Andrew for replying to the DotNetOpenAuth tagged queries.